# Use multiple JSON objects in an API call using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am looking for a way to batch query multiple JSON objects in a single call, which has a query limit of X, in JavaScript/NodeJS.

The API looks something like this `https://api.website.com/users` and the query parameter is `login`.

I have a JSON file that contains all the logins like `["John","Maria","David","Simon","Michelle","Bob"]`

Using my two examples the GET request should look something like this if the query limit is set to 3

1. `https://api.website.com/users?login=John&login=Maria&login=David`
2. `https://api.website.com/users?login=Simon&login=Michelle&login=Bob`

I have no idea how to achieve that I cannot seem to find matching search results online.

Comment: Is your question "How can I make an API that allows that?" or "Can I make batch API calls to an API that does not support this?". "the query limit is set to 3" - > who imposes this?

Comment: The website's API totally support that kind of calls, they set the query limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) constructor. There are different ways to initialize it. You could pass a 2D array as the argument to it like this:

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams( [["foo", "1"], ["bar", "2"]] )

console.log( searchParams.toString() ) // foo=1&bar=2
```

So, the 2D array you need pass to the `URLSearchParams` constructor looks something like this:

```
[["login","John"],["login","Maria"],["login","David"]]
```

- Loop the array in a step of `limit` using `i += limit`
- Create a chunk using `users.slice(i, i+limit)` (This creates an array like this `["John","Maria","David"]` )
- `map` this array to get a 2D array mentioned above with the first index as `"login"`
- pass it to `URLSearchParams` constructor

```js
const users = ["John", "Maria", "David", "Simon", "Michelle", "Bob"],
      limit = 3

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += limit) {
  const chunk = users.slice(i, i+limit),
        pairs = chunk.map(c => ["login", c]),
        searchParam = new URLSearchParams(pairs),
        fullURL = "https://api.website.com/users?" +  searchParam.toString();
   
   console.log(fullURL)
}
```

---

If the map and 2D array initialization is too confusing, you could loop through the chunk and `append` to the search params object

```js
const users = ["John", "Maria", "David", "Simon", "Michelle", "Bob"],
      limit = 3

for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i += limit) {
  const chunk = users.slice(i, i + limit),
        searchParam = new URLSearchParams();

  for (const name of chunk) {
    searchParam.append("login", name)
  }

  const fullURL = "https://api.website.com/users?" + searchParam.toString();
  console.log(fullURL)
}
```